# Headset not working once call is established

Tags: sinch

We have deployed Sinch into our app and all is working good except for a specific headset under a specific OS:

- This is a USB headset which connects through a wireless USB dongle
- It works fine with our Mac and Windows 10 computers
- It connects correctly to our Windows 7 computers and we can hear audio (for example by watching a youtube video) and can record using its microphone
- If we use it in our app to make a call, we can hear the ringing sound but then once the call is started neither the speaker nor the microphone will work. I do not see any Sinch errors or warnings in the console. This is running in Chrome

So, my question is: is there any debugging tool that we could use to try to find out why these headsets do not work during a Sinch call ?

Comment: Are you getting the question to allow mic? If not thats the first problem, if you are you select in chrome what microphone and speaker to use

Comment: Yes, i get the question and i have chosen the proper mike add headphone. As i said, i can hear the ringing tone, it is when the call stats that things stop working